# Avoid table with empty cells

Tags: tables, empty

We need to show the list of students with their scores who study different subjects. Putting it in a table results in a lot of empty cells (as shown below). What is the effective way of showing the list? We donot want to group the students based on subjects because if we have to find the weekest student in the institution, sorting becomes a pain.

```
---------------------------------------------
Name         Math      Economics     English
---------------------------------------------
Hypatia       55                       25
Ramanujan     55                       25
Karl                      32           25
Marx                      32           25
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can a place a label in empty cells for example n/a (not applicable). This will enhance the alignment of the columns and rows. Also, it will give a visual balance in the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for the sugession. But in our case, a lot of cells will contain the filler text. which is annoying to the user.

Comment: You can put a simple "-" (dash). It won't look as cluttered. You can also change the color of the empty cells.

Comment: Thanks Sevban. But the hyphen can mean anything like there is no data even if the subject is not relevant for the student's profile. This will be misleading.